# What does "on hold" on Stack Exchange mean?

Tags: discussion

The question I asked has been flagged as ***on hold***. What does it mean? (I am not a native English speaker)

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425369/angle-between-two-lines)

Comment: The same thing it means on every Stack Exchange site: no one else can answer as your question is off-topic; *on hold* is defined in many general-reference books. Dictionary, thesaurus, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your info.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_hold

Comment: No one can answer it until it is reopened. Which might happen if you edit your question to improve its quality to the point where people will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say something is on hold when it is paused or stopped for a while. Your question is not related to programming so it is 'on hold', i.e , it cannot be answered till it is shifted to the right forum.